Ubuntu flavors in encrypted partition with LVM?
Unfortunately, both installers used for Desktop Ubuntu flavors, i.e. subiquity and calamares, are currently able to properly install Ubuntu/Lubuntu/... into an encrypted partition with an LVM inside to allow multiple partitions (e.g. if other file systems are needed for applications like LXD), which is a regression.
In contrast, the old fashion console based installer for Ubuntu server is still able to do it properly.
What is the recommended and official way/workaround to install Ubuntu desktop versions into encrypted partitions with LVM?
Install the server edition, remove cloud-init, and install e.g. lubuntu-desktop?
Anything else needed?

You mention subiquity which is the Ubuntu Server installer; both saying it has the problem you're asking to fix; then later asking if using it will resolve the issue?  Ubuntu Desktop started using the ubuntu-desktop-installer at 23.04, with ubiquity offered as an alternate ISO (legacy installer) for 23.04 & 23.10.   FYI:  Prior to 23.04 the ubuntu-desktop-installer was named canary installer, however subiquity has been used for Server installs for much longer time.

If you do a server install, you can add desktop. It used to give this automatically, but I have not installer server lately, so not sure. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel You can install tasksel or just install desktop from terminal as shown in link.

@guiverc: Yes. As I said, the graphical desktop version and the console based server version of subiquity do behave differently. The graphical version has the problem, while the console/server version behaves well.

The Desktop installer is ubuntu-desktop-installer and not subiquity, though it does call subiquity code for parts of the install process so subiquity messages can appear (ie. same backend which is coded to report subiquity) but the Desktop installer is not subiquity  (The ubuntu-desktop-installer was called canary installer prior for 22.10 & earlier; 21.10/impish being first release with canary available for QA)
